# Right-angled triangle ABC

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

(I'm only a Year 7 so please explain clearly how you found the solution)

In the right angled triangle $ABC$, a point $M$ on the hypotenuse $BC$ is such that $AM$ is perpendicular to $BC$. Also, $MC$ is $8$ cm longer than $BM$, and the ratio $AB:AC=3:5$
How many centimetres is the hypotenuse?

I started by calling the length of $BM=y$, and $MC=y+8$  and then using similar triangle ratios created fractions $\frac{AM}{MC} =  \frac{BM}{AM}$ which cancelled out to make $\frac{BM}{MC}$ which substitutes into $\frac{y}{y+8}$ but then I got stuck. Can anyone help me?. By the way, the answer is $17$.

Comment: Hint:  We know that, for some $t$, $BA=3t$ and $AC=5t$.  Now use similar triangles. We know that $\Delta AMC\sim \Delta BAC \sim \Delta BMA$.

Comment: what are you calling _t_? @lulu

Comment: We are told  that the two legs have the ratio $\frac 35$.  That means that, for some $t$ we have $BA=3t$ and $AC =5t$.  To see this, write $t=\frac {BA}3$.  Then $\frac 35 =\frac {BA}{AC}=\frac {3t}{AC}\implies AC=5t$.

Comment: To elaborate on my hint:  using $t$, and introducing a variable $z=AM$, you could write out the Pythagorean Theorem for each of the three right triangles.  That would give us three quadratic equations in the three variables $t,z,y$.  That's not great, as it is not so easy to solve simultaneous quadratic equations.  Also, this method doesn't use the fact that the three right triangles are all similar.  That's very powerful!  So I am advising that you write out what you can from the similarity.  You don't need to use the variable $z$ at all (though you could solve for it as well if you wanted).

Comment: @bio, Is the answer $\frac{17}{4}$?

Comment: Can I please just get an answer?

Comment: This is not a homework answering service. You need to make an effort. The clues provided by @lulu are enough for you to solve the problem, but let me take it one step further. (1) All three triangles in your problem are similar (do you see why?). (2) Similar triangles have the same length ratios between equivalent sides. (3) In this case, this means that $\frac{3}{5}=\frac{AM}{MC}=\frac{BM}{AM}$. Insert your expressions for $BM$ and $MC$ and algebra will do the rest.

Comment: Oh sorry, the answer is $17 cm$

Comment: @Jens  I know that would be y/y+8 but then what?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

[image: Diagram for the given situation]
Since $ \angle AMC =  \angle AMB =  90°$ , apply the Pythagoras Theorem in $   \triangle AMC $ and $ \triangle AMB $
$$\implies (y+8)^2 + x^2 = (5k)^2$$
$$\implies y^2 + 16y + 64 + x^2 = 25k^2 ...(1)$$

Also, $$x^2 + y^2 = (3k)^2$$
$$\implies x^2 + y^2 = 9k^2 ....(2)$$

Now, substituting $(2)$  into  $(1)$ , 
$$9k^2 + 64 + 16y = 25k^2$$
$$\implies 16y + 64 = 16k^2$$
$$\implies y + 4 = k^2$$ (dividing both sides by $16$ )

$$\implies BC = 2y + 8 = 2k^2$$

Now, on applying Pythagoras Theorem in $\triangle BAC$ ,  we get

$$ 9k^2 + 25k^2 = 4k^4$$
$$\implies 34 = 4k^2$$ (dividing both sides by $ k^2 $ )

$$\implies BC = 2k^2 = 17 cm $$ (dividing both sides by $ 2 $ )

NOTE: To clear your confusion regarding $3k$ and $5k$, the $k$ has been written because $AB$ and $AC$ may not necessarily be $3cm$ and $5cm$ respectively (and they are not in this case also). In order to maintain the ratio, we have expressed $AB$ as $3k$ and $AC$ as $5k$, where $k$ can be any positive real number. I hope it's clear. If it's not, then please write in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

Call $BM=y$. We know that $AB=0.6AC$. Time to invoke Euclid: 
$$(0.6AC)^2=y\cdot(2y+8)\text{ and } AC^2=(y+8)\cdot (2y+8).$$
Now divide the first equation by the second to solve
$$0.36=\frac{y}{y+8}.$$

EDIT: If you replace $8$ by $a$ and $0.6$ by $t$, the hypotenuse will be
$$a\cdot\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}.$$

(Provided that $t\neq1$; in this case there is no solution unless $a=0$.)

Comment: i haven't learnt about euclid yet

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Euclid.27s_proof